# Solder paste, is it standard?

Tags: pcb

When it comes down to having PCBs produced is solder paste applied to the pads so I can stick the IC's down or do I have to add paste myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to apply paste yourself. Once applied it deteriorates quite quickly.

Conventional soldering equipment can be used with surface-mount devices; I do it all the time.

Comment: Once applied to a component does it stay there for the time required to place say 80-100 components?

Comment: It's good for a few hours. This is what I use: http://www.warton-metals.co.uk/solderpaste.html. Warton states up to 24 hours after application and three days after the components have been mounted.

Answer (score 3):

No. You get bare, dry boards.  Solder paste should be used as soon as possible after application, because the flux contained in the paste will deteriorate when exposed to oxygen.

If you're doing mass manufacture yourself, consider getting a stencil made for your board.  I've heard good things about [Stencils Unlimited](http://www.stencilsunlimited.com) for small-volume work.  Then, you just squirt out a little solder paste at one end, run a (sharp steel) squeegee over the stencil, and lift - Perfect solder paste application in seconds!

If you're doing just a few/small boards and the $125 investment in a prototype stencil feels steep, I'd just use standard solder wire. Put a small dome on the PCB pad, position the part, heat the pin until it drops to the PCB, and you're off to the races.